# How to validate a DATETIME between two dates

Tags: sql, validation, datetime

I am trying to check if a coupon is valid between two given dates.
I don't have much SQL experience but currently the code is using `BETWEEN` to try to validate and the issue I am running into is that the `endDate` expires at midnight of day before (ex.`10/12/2012 00:00:00.000` evaluates to midnight of `10/11`) and I need it to extend through the midnight of `10/12`.
So I am wondering if appending/adding `23:59:59` to the end date is the best way of performing this evaluation?

Currently Using:

```
ca.CreateDate between co.StartDate and co.EndDate
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `BETWEEN` for continuously varying values.

You need...

```
    ca.CreateDate >= co.StartDate
AND ca.CreateDate <  co.EndDate
```

But you also need to add one day to your end date values.  Either in the code *(`co.EndDate + 1` or similar)*, or in the data it self.

For example, if you want all times for the 1st week of 2012...

```
WHERE
      theDateTime >= '01 Jan 2012'
  AND theDateTime <  '08 Jan 2012'
```

This even applies to other levels of granularity.

```
-- First 12 hours of the day
WHERE
      theDateTime >= '01 Jan 2012 00:00'
  AND theDateTime <  '01 Jan 2012 12:00'

-- All of Jan
WHERE
      theDateTime >= '01 Jan 2012'
  AND theDateTime <  '01 Feb 2012'
```

Comment: Thank you just wondering the benefits of your solution instead of between so I can learn

Comment: @AndrewBrower - `BETWEEN` is most useful for discrete values, such as whole numbers. `BETWEEN 1 and 7` makes sense if you're looking at integers. But would you write `BETWEEN 1 AND 7.99999999999` for floats? Or would you write `>= 1 AND < 8`? DateTimes are continuously varying and not discrete, so I would not recommend using `BETWEEN`.  *(It also makes getting whole months much simpler, as well as other incidental benefits.)*

Comment: Yeah I understand the syntax I guess my real question is does < endDate evaluate as 23:59:59 or does it compare it to 00:00:00.00 like it is in database resulting in the need to +1 the endDate

Comment: This is an example of an `Inclusive` lower boundary, and an `Exclusive` upper boundary.  Such a pattern is infinitely accurate for continuously varying values.

Comment: `< '01 Feb 2012'` includes every moment in January.  Even up to `23:59:59.99999999999999999999999999999999999999`.  That's the point, it's resolution is not dependant on how accurately you can define your boundary.  If you define the boundary for `BETWEEN` to the nearest minute, you'll miss the seconds after it.  If you define it to the second, you miss the milliseconds after it.  Using `<` is perfectly accurate, and you don't even have to think about resolution any more.

Comment: disreguard needed to update to see your comment thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

If that is the case.. Adding +1 to endDate would do..